# Phonegap/Android localstorage issue on Android 2.x, 3.x

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage

I have a problem with localstorage on Android 2.x and 3.x.

When the app is launched for the first time, the app fetches some data from a remote web service and then stores those data in the localstorage.

The problem is that whenever new data is fetched and then trying to update the localstorage items, their values never change and remain the same as the first time. This means that only if I uninstall the app and reinstall, my app can fetch the updated data.

In other words, my localstorage items cannot be updated, they always keep their first value.

This does not happen on Adnroid 4.x nor on my desktop Chrome.

I hope my issue is clear and I appreciate your help.

Thanks